# RSocket dependency issue using Gradle6.3 with Spring boot 2.2..6.Release in Apache Archiva

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, archiva, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

My issue is similar to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20348 but still, I am not able to find the appropriate solution.
I am using apache archiva2.2.5, Gradle 6.3, and Spring boot 2.2.6.Release.

When I try to build the project, it tries to download "rsocket-bom-1.0.0-RC6.module" from my remote repository and it fails. I checked the file "rsocket-bom-1.0.0-RC6.module" doesn't exist in my remote repo neither it exists in maven central repository.
[image: Screenshot]
How do I resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Always use a stable version for development. Its just a matter of time that it will be fixed in springboot. Its nothing to do with gradle though.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://.... your url here .../artifactory/maven-all"
        metadataSources {
            mavenPom()
            artifact()
            ignoreGradleMetadataRedirection()
        }
    }
}
```

It worked for me :-)